# R use directory name as a variable

Tags: r, variables, batch-file, directory

please help me for the basic question, I want to change the work directory by using`setwd(/media/A/A1/)`, but I have hundreds of directory like A1, A2, A2.... Is it possible to set the number behind A as a variable? Any help or guidance hugely appreciated!

Comment: `setwd()` takes a character argument. Use the `paste`-function.

Comment: Maybe you could put them all in one folder and make that the working directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example in a`for` loop.

```
for(i in 1:10){
     setwd(paste0("/media/A/A", i))
     }
```